# How to remove a subset of items from an Entity Framework Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity framework `EntityCollection`.

I need to delete all items that match a given where clause from the database.  This is my existing code:

```
// Perform the deletes
foreach (var deleteReq in order.Requirements.Where(x=>!orderContract.Requirements.Any(y=>y.RequirementId==x.RequirementId)))
{
    order.Requirements.Remove(deleteReq);
}
```

Basically I am trying to remove anything from the order.Requirements collection that is not in the orderContract.Requirements collection (matching on an Id).

As you may guess, this code throws and exception because I am modifying the collection I am iterating.

Normally I would just use `RemoveAll()` but the `EntityCollection` does not support that method.

So... How can I delete all the records I need to?

Comment: Why you can't collect removable items in a list? collection size is big?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a seperate list and it seems to have worked:

```
// Perform the deletes
var reqsToDelete = order.Requirements.Where(x=>!orderContract.Requirements.Any(y=>y.RequirementId==x.RequirementId)).ToList();
foreach (var deleteReq in reqsToDelete)
{
    order.Requirements.Remove(deleteReq);
}
```

That way, when I remove the item from the order.Requirements list, it is not affecting the list that I am iterating.

Answer (score 6):

collect all the Requirement entities you want to delete into a list.

Then remove each one of those from the Requirements entity collection rather than from order.Requirements.

Comment: Alas, at the location I am doing the deleting it would be very hard to get the Requirements entity collection.  (I am in an AutoMapper ITypeConverter.)

Comment: At least, you will not be able to delete within foreach loop, try collecting it in a list. Then outside the loop try deleting it each one manually.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to EF6, there is a `RemoveRange` method for better performance and cleaner API

```
var deleteQuery = order
    .Requirements
    .Where(x=> !orderContract.Requirements.Any(y=>y.RequirementId == x.RequirementId));

order.Requirements.RemoveRange(deleteQuery);
```

Now, the EF wont load each item before remove, as it is a case in the accepted answer.